# When reviewing / viewing an edit, can we show the title diff in a more readable format?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edit-summary, diff

Currently we only seem to have to option of viewing both the old and new versions of an edit to the question body - the title only seems to show inline differences, such as

[image]

It takes me some thinking to work out what the two titles actually are, in this case

> Regular expression to find in string

and

> How to find all matches in a string with a regex in PHP

This is by no means one of the more obscure examples, but I would find it a lot easier when reviewing edits in particular to be able to read both versions of the title on their own, in the same way that I can with the question body.

Comment: Well, you managed to get the two versions right, what's the problem actually?

Comment: that's kinda missing the point of the feature request. If they gave me the differences to read in binary I could probably "get it right"...

Comment: I was originally thinking that if you selected to view the two copies of the question body separately, you should also be able to view the two titles in the same way

Answer (score 8):

I definitely consider this a problem as well. Here's what I just encountered.

[image: Say what now]

The two titles are basically exploded into 11 pieces and the reviewer has to do a mental puzzle to figure out the *before* and *after* versions. Sure, it can be done, but it's frustrating to spend so much time on something irrelevant to the task at hand.

My suggestion is to never let this puzzle go beyond four pieces on a single line. Maybe even less. If that happens, show the whole old line as deleted and the new one as added.

[image]