# Suggested difference highlights title difference by line not by word

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, diff

Suggested Edits 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23434701
[image]

**Expected**:
Only the insert word is highlighted

Comment: no repro on Win 10 Chrome 75 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnJNt.png

Comment: no repo on Ubuntu (Pop!) Chrome 75 or Firefox 67.

Comment: I don't see it on Firefox 67.  Could this be dark theme related?

Comment: This is probably the result of a user-script, fixing a usability issue as [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310843/when-reviewing-viewing-an-edit-can-we-show-the-title-diff-in-a-more-readable).

Comment: If you want a dark theme, mine fully supports code highlighting and revision diffs: https://stackapps.com/q/8053/9011

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, seems like it. Probably folded into that theme used by OP. Sort of related - that "bug" annoys the hell out of me, as well. Although not always - if the change is, say, a single word, it's better to show that, but if it's indeed something like what's shown in the other post, then it's better to show the line change. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be any middle ground. Unless there is a toggle for the two displays or something. Sorry, just wanted to rant about diffs.

Comment: This userscript caused this - https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox

Comment: yeah this was due to SOX, there is a black toggle icon at the left of the title (if you look really closely) but it was mostly hidden due to the unsupported (at least for now!) dark theme being used. (cc @VLAZ in case you want this feature :P)